# How to disable task / app changing keys and functionality in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

I frequently use Windows 10 in a virtual machine and find that I only ever want to use `alt-tab` for task switching.  I'd like to disable all kinds of other task switching such as `win-tab`, the "Task View" button and every other key combo involved in such things.  For some reason using these various keys (except for `alt-tab`) really screws up control for various apps from graphical / 3D apps to even games.

How can all such task changing functionality except for `alt-tab` be disabled in Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can change it but you could try with Autohotkey. Though I've never tested it under virtual machine. 
For example to completely block the left Win key use this script:

```
LWin::return
```